# Order by sum from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have these 2 tables:

`School`:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS school (" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "name CHAR NOT NULL" +
                ");"
```

`Teacher`:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teacher ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "school_id NOT NULL, " +
                "name CHAT NOT NULL, " +
                "wage REAL NOT NULL," +
                "CONSTRAINT fk_school_id FOREIGN KEY (school_id) " +
                "REFERENCES school (id) ON DELETE CASCADE" +
                ");"
```

I need to select all schools ordering by the total amount salary is expend on the teacher staff.

Example:
Teachers

```
id, school_id, name, wage
1, 1, 'teacher1', 2000
2, 1, 'teacher2', 1500
3, 2, 'teacher3', 5600
4, 3, 'teacher4', 4300
5, 4, 'teacher5', 5000
6, 4, 'teacher6', 3500
7, 4, 'teacher7', 4000
```

This should be the expected result:

```
school.id, school.name
4, 'school 4'
2, 'school 2'
3, 'school 3'
1, 'school 1'
```

Comment: I tried this, very close to the answer below, but I don't know how to order by the SUM.

     SELECT school.id, school.name, SUM(teacher.wage)
     FROM school JOIN teachers on teacher.school_id = school.id
     GROUP BY school.id, school.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL query could be :

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, SUM(t.wage)
FROM school AS s
JOIN teachers AS t on t.school.id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id, s.name
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply,

I'm getting this error: "Error while executing query: near "3": syntax error"

Comment: op called the salary wage and you should order by `SUM(t.salary)` since the sum isn't part of the expected output

Comment: @Aツ, I edit my answer for wage, thanks. op have SUM in SELECT query look at his comment